# iPhone Wi-Fi Manager SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, wifi, toggle

I'm attempting several methods trying to enable/disable Wi-Fi (toggle). Here are some things I am trying:

```
//Enable
WiFiManagerClientEnable(WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0));
//Disable
WiFiManagerClientDisable(WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0));
```

-and-

```
//Enable
WiFiManagerClientSetProperty(WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0), @"AllowEnable", kCFBooleanTrue);
//Disable
WiFiManagerClientSetProperty(WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0), @"AllowEnable", kCFBooleanFalse);
```

Each of those end up crashing the app, even though I have an exception function (@try{}).
I've imported the MobileWiFi.framework and everything, just cant seem to get this to work. Are these the correct methods I need to call to be able to enable/disable Wi-Fi?

**NOTE: NOT FOR APP STORE :-)**

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018110/accessing-using-the-mobilewifi-framework Do you know of any user mode apps that have been able to enable or disable wifi on a non-jailbroken iphone? There is a way to simply flag your app as requiring wifi but that's about all I know of.

Comment: That doesnt enable/disable wifi, just returns certain info.

Comment: Hello, Am also trying something similar, can you please tell me more about the frameworks u have added and how to do this in xcode. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### From Application

```
notify_post("com.yourcompany.yourapp.yournotification");
```

### From Dylib

```
#import <SpringBoard/SBWiFiManager.h>

HOOK(SpringBoard, applicationDidFinishLaunching$, void, id app) {
    //Listen for events via DARWIN NOTIFICATION CENTER
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), NULL,
     &NotificationReceivedCallback, CFSTR("com.yourcompany.yourapp.yournotification"), NULL, 
      CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorCoalesce);
}

//THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
static void NotificationReceivedCallback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, 
                                            void *observer, CFStringRef name, 
                                            const void *object, CFDictionaryRef 
                                            userInfo) 
{ 
    [[objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager") sharedInstance] setWiFiEnabled:NO];
}
```

Comment: I tried [[objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager") sharedInstance] setWiFiEnabled:NO];
 in a sample iOS 4.2.1 app but its doing nothing. Is it possible that the function call is not working because its from my app and its not a dylib loaded under SpringBoard?

Comment: This will not work from an app and MUST be called from a .dylib.

Comment: Okay thanks. I haven't developed .dylib till now. Can you please point me towards a link which explains how to develop dylib for iphone. Is this a normal dylib for springboard or something like mobilesubstrate toggle?

Comment: You can scope out github.com .. there are plenty of open source tweaks there.

Comment: To be clear, `SBWiFiManager` is a class that only exists in SpringBoard. To call it, one must be running inside SpringBoard as either a dynamic library or a framework.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I am now trying to compile dylib (made with theos) but I am getting following error: "error: ‘objc_getClass’ was not declared in this scope" (along with many other errors). How to include objective c headers in theos?
Also function 'HOOK' is not being recognized.

Comment: I am still not able to use HOOK.

Comment: If you are using logos try `%hook`.

Comment: How can I use your kind of HOOK?

Comment: Thanks!!! I got it working with theos using this tutorial :) http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-your-first-tweak/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable WiFi on the phone. The user is responsible for this action through the Settings App, this capability is not available through the SDK.

-t

Comment: Well, I'm not writing the code for the App Store, my project is setup to use Private Frameworks.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, it seemed an appropriate response to me.

Comment: becaz the OP has stated that it is not for App Store already :-)