# Turn Wifi on/off for iphone from an application

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

I need to turn on or off the wifi in the iphone.  Any ways of doing it? Or is it forbidden (private framework)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All applications written with the public SDK are sandboxed. They only have access to the properties and data which Apple deems feasible to use within that sandbox. I am afraid Wi-fi doesn't come in the list

Pls take a look at this SO question [iPhone Wi-Fi Manager SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053114/iphone-wi-fi-manager-sdk) and this [discussion](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3394-howto-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-bluetooth.html)

Comment: In short: Apple doesn't allow fiddling with WiFi, the corresponding framework is private and your app will be rejected if you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Too bad I can't.  Worth asking though!