# Turn on/Off bluetooth, wifi and other settings from custom application in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, settings, wifi

Is there any framework or utility available for making settings like wifi/bluetooth from iphone application in IOS. I need to develop such an application that can set the wifi and bluetooth on/off.

Comment: Is your app for in-house distribution? If not, the app won't be approved in the AppStore.

Comment: Yes, I developing it for In-House.

Comment: Not true. Apps will get approved. I can concur.

Comment: Class BluetoothManager = objc_getClass("BluetoothManager"); may work for bluetooth. Can any one help me for other setting options like wifi, aeroplane mode, etc.

Comment: Please check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518406/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-bluetooth-and-or-wifi-on-and-off-programatically-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't provide any APIs for doing this out of the box, The case is different with Jailbroken iOS devices though. SBSettings is an app that does all what you asked but works only on a jailbroken iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Toggling bluetooth was possible using the GameKit APIs, though it is not a straight forward method. If you want pointers on this i can share the links ( need to do some searching on my bookmarks history though) a simple google search would reveal this method. But i understand your requirement is much more than this one, so like the user24921 said, you need a Jailbreak iPhone/iPad for accessing those Private APIs.

Comment: Do the GameKit APIs you mention include toggling BT discoverability?  I'd love to see a link or two if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is for in-house distribution, it doesn't require to go through AppStore so it won't be reviewed. Here is an answer that maybe can help you: [Programmatically turn on bluetooth in the iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Class BluetoothManager = objc_getClass("BluetoothManager");
bluetoothManager = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance];
[bluetoothManager setEnabled:YES];
[bluetoothManager setPowered:YES];
```

Comment: What about the wifi and other settings.

Comment: A simple search ends up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053114/iphone-wi-fi-manager-sdk