# iphone - making Wifi-list app

Tags: iphone, list, wifi

I want to programmatically show a list of available wifi on my iphone.

I tried to run this program but it doesn't work.
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler

Does anyone have any tutorial or sample code about creating a list of wifi-network.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk)

Comment: See also [Accessing & Using the MobileWiFi.framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018110/accessing-using-the-mobilewifi-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's not possible. I didn't try it myself. But I just read the first few lines of the description of Stumbler. There's the following line:

> Stumbler can not be distributed through the app store, as it uses private APIs!

So I don't think it's possible to create an application that lists all WiFis. On iPhone this is a part of the Operating System.

Sandro Meier

Comment: I'm making an enterprise app and I think private api can be used in enterprise version.