# Apple 802.11 API on IOS6.1 - anyone have the correct bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios6.1, wifi

I am trying to use the Apple 802.11 private library on a project to help detect the SSID and signal strength for WiFi hotspots in the area.   This has been discussed in other threads such as:

[iPhone Wifi Scan Stumbler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660169/iphone-wifi-scan-stumbler)

YES I know this is not "supported" and requires private APIs and that I will not be able to offer this APP on the app store.   This is for a private application that is just to help us with some network testing.

From my research - it looked like the bundle that had the 80211 library was at `/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/WiFiManager.bundle/WiFiManager` in **iOS4**

That got changed to:  `/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration`  in **iOS5**

I'm looking for the **location of it in iOS 6.1** (I am running XCode 4 if that makes any difference). When I try to run this code using

```
libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/WiFiManager.bundle/WiFiManager", RTLD_LAZY);
```

or

```
libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration", RTLD_LAZY);
```

I get an image not found error, which leads me to believe that Apple move this once again.

Does anyone know where the 80211 library lives now or if there is another way to get WiFi details (SSID and Signal strength)?

Thanks
Ryan
Ryan@MassachusettsWebDesigns.com

Answer (score 1):

```
libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration", RTLD_LAZY);`
```

this method is fine in my jailbreak device(version iOS6.1) .