# Wifi Scanner for iOS8

Tags: ios8, rssi, signal-strength

How do i find out the Wifi signal strengths(RSSI) in iOS8 ?

I know that Apple restricts apps from accessing the Wi-Fi data/API directly and will not be accepted in AppStore. I found a private API called Stumbler which is supposed to be doing the same. Here is the link to it. [Accessing & Using the MobileWiFi.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018110/accessing-using-the-mobilewifi-framework)

networks = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
void* library = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration", RTLD_LAZY);

int (*apple80211Open)(void*) = (int(*)(void*))dlsym(library, "Apple80211Open");

int (*apple80211Bind)(void*, NSString*) = (int(*)(void*, NSString*))dlsym(library, "Apple80211BindToInterface");
apple80211Close = (int(*)(void*))dlsym(library, "Apple80211Close");
apple80211Scan= (int(*)(void*, NSArray**, void*))dlsym(library, "Apple80211Scan");

void *airport = NULL;
apple80211Open(&airport);

apple80211Bind(airport, @"en0");

NSArray* arrNetworks = nil;
apple80211Scan(airport, &arrNetworks, (__bridge void *)(networks));

//"networks" is an array of NSDictionary objects for all the visible Wi-Fi networks

apple80211Close(airport);
dlclose(library);
```

Somehow this is not working in iOS8. Anyone has any idea how to get this working?? Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Though my problem is not solved yet. I found this app "Airport Utility" which does the exact same thing that i want. It has a Wi-Fi scan which shows all available wifis in an area. Anyone has any idea how this is happening? Any leads on what APIs to use for iOS8?

Comment: No way to do in iOS unless JB. Even JB is not working as you mentioned in iOS8. Airport Utility is native to apple and can't be used. Can be used on Mac OS X via NSTask but not possible on iOS as NSTask is not allowed.